# How to close the loop if one of the task is completed in asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have 3 tasks. -

```
def task_a(): 
    while True:
        file.write()
        asyncio.sleep(10)

def task_b():
    while True:
        file.write()
        asyncio.sleep(10)


def task_c():
    # do something
```

main.py -

```
try:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    A = loop.create_task(task_a)
    B = loop.create_task(task_b)
    C = loop.create_task(task_c)

    awaitable_pending_tasks = asyncio.all_tasks()
    execution_group = asyncio.gather(*awaitable_pending_tasks, return_exceptions=True)
        fi_execution = loop.run_until_complete(execution_group)
finally:
    loop.run_forever()
```

I want to make sure that the loop is exited when the task_c is completed.
Tried with loop.close() in finally but since it's async, it closes in between.

task_a and task_b write to a file and there is another process running that checks the time the file was modified. If it's greater than a minute it will result in an error(which I don't want) hence I've put the while loop in it and once its written I added a sleep()

Once task_c is complete, I need the loop to stop.

Other answers on StackOverflow looked complicated to understand.
Any way we can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call `loop.run_until_complete` or `asyncio.run` (but not `run_forever`) to run a function that prepares the tasks you need and then only `await`s the one you want to terminate the loop (untested):

```
async def main():
    asyncio.create_task(task_a)
    asyncio.create_task(task_b)
    await task_c
    tasks = set(asyncio.all_tasks()) - set([asyncio.current_task()])
    for t in tasks:
        t.cancel()
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)

asyncio.run(main())
# or asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: The solution does execute task_c but gets stuck while doing asyncio.gather
trace - 
if child.cancel():\n  [Previous line repeated 491 more times]\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.8/asyncio/tasks.py\", line 711, in cancel\n    if self.done():\nRecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object", "exc_text": null, "stack_info": null, "lineno": 51}


I handled the case by passing the loop to task_c and stopping the loop at the end of task_c. I know it's actually a bad way because I am closing the loop in the method.

Comment: Maybe you should exclude `asyncio.current_task()` from the set of tasks you're canceling.

Comment: Earlier I had removed the await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True) and handled the asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError but removing the current task from tasks solved it.

A million thanks to the asyncio king @user4815162342  :)
Any resource where I can learn asyncio in more depth?

Can you explain what you did after
asyncio.create_task(task_a)
asyncio.create_task(task_b)

Comment: @Arjunsingh *Can you explain what you did after...* - I'm not sure I understand the question. I simply awaited `task_c` - or are you asking what `await` means?

Comment: Got it. I had misunderstood the use of create_task. I thought that it doesn't run the task in background. But in actual, create_task here runs the tasks task_a and task_b in background. Then we await task_c which is also added to the loop consisting of task_a and task_b. We then get all the tasks rather than the current task and cancel that since they are in while loop they will never get over. asyncio.gather() then removes them from the loop gracefully and after that all the tasks are finished, it comes to a halt. Is this correct or I misunderstood anything?

Comment: @Arjunsingh Correct. Note that `asyncio.gather()` is just a convenience function to await the tasks and (when requested) suppress exceptions, here needed only to avoid an annoying warning. You could await them in a loop, and wrap each await in `suppress(CancelledError)`, but it'd be more code.

Comment: Any resource you would suggest to learn asyncio in more depth?

Comment: @Arjunsingh [This](https://realpython.com/async-io-python/) might be a good one.